# How do I get rid of an Ender Dragon on a Realm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I accidentally spawned an Ender Dragon on my realm. I tried multiple commands and nothing is working. I even tried using the existing commands on my realm. But it is still not working. So how do I get rid of it on my realm?

I tried the following, which didn't work:

```
/kill ender_dragon
```

With the following error:

> Entity ender_dragon could not be found

Comment: What are the multiple commands you've tried to use? We can't really provide an answer if it ends up being something you've already tried, but neglected to specify.

Comment: I tried /kill and I tried to enter the Ender Dragon's entity ID. But it say's:

Comment: Entity ender_dragon could not be found

Comment: Yes. That keep's happening when I try to kill it. And I don't understand because the Ender Dragon's Entity ID is ender_dragon.

Answer (score 2):

You've inserted "ender_dragon" as a literal player name. If you want to target generic entities, you will need to use the `@e` (entity) selector, and specify the savegame ID in the `type` parameter:

```
/kill @e[type=ender_dragon]
```

Comment: Lol I don't understand what @e means. So, can you tell me what that exactly means?

Comment: Oh nevermind. It means entity.

Comment: But it still isn't working. I can only do specific commands.

Comment: @BrycethegreatYT "@e" means "everyone". So the commands to which it is applied affects all entities (of a specific type). By the way, if you consider that the answer above helped you, please mark it as accepted by pressing the checkmark button.

Comment: Don't forget: The dragon **must** be loaded or else the command won't work (within view of any player, or be in a spawn chunk and same dimension).